# Putting glowing, debossed text on an uneven surface

Tags: modeling

I want to put glowing, inset text on an uneven rock surface, as though it had been carved there.[image]

Comment: This is best done using a normal map and color texture that are applied to the rock.

Comment: you could use the Knife Project tool to draw the letters on the rock, then extrude inwards and bevel, but as Rjg says, it's certainly easier to use a Normal map